# Regex Price in a String

Tags: regex

I found this regex which finds prices like 1.00 or $1.00. But it also returns true for values that are 3 or more digits long like '365'.

```
/([\d,]+.\d+)+/i
```

Is there anyway to modify this regex to return true for all types of prices that are floating point but excludes 3 consecutive digits like '365' or '1000', etc.:

1.00
$1.00

Comment: I think you did not copy the regex correctly from where you found it. It has mistakes that are too obvious. As the answers below point out, `.` should be escaped. Also, if you are matching just digits and symbols, capitalization should not matter, so your `i` at the end is useless. You should check your regex and correct it above first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should find all single digit numbers, with decimal points. So:

```
1.xxx
2.xxx
...
9.xxx
```

but not

`365` or `365.000`

```
/(\d\.\d+)/i
```

Comment: @miky-dinescu that regex still returns values like '365' true.

Comment: @user450837 - i fixed it now.. I had two errors previously.  Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, instead of '.', you need to use '\.'. What you have would match anything, while the second matches just the character '.'   .

```
/([\d,]+\.\d+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` matches everything, so, escape it:

```
/([\d,]+\.\d+)+/i
```

I'd even do this:

```
/\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*\.\d+)+/i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to match prices in a piece of text, such as:

> 1.00 is a valid price and so are $1.50 and  $10.12, but not $200.90 or
>   £1000.10

Then this will return `1.00`, `$1.50` and `$10.12` as matches.

`(^|\W{1})\d{1,2}\.\d{2}`

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the regex parts extension by using `{a,b}`

```
\d{1,2}\.\d{2}$
```